# Merge and fill two dataframes in Pandas with different time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes I'd like to merge in Pandas. They both have a datetime column that I am merging on, however, one has rows every minute and 5 minutes (depending on the year), while the other dataframe has rows every 15 minutes.  If I do an outer join, I can merge them, but only the rows every 15 minutes will have data from both dataframes. I'd like to copy the 15 minute data and fill in each of the 1 or 5 minute rows with this data. So, data from 12:00AM would populate all rows up to and including 12:14AM. Then, 12:15AM would be copied and fill in up to 12:29AM etc.  Does that make sense? How can I accomplish this? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080542/merging-combining-two-dataframes-with-different-frequency-time-series-indexes-in) seems similar but I'm not sure how to implement for my exact scenario especially given that my one dataframe changes from 5 minute to 1 minute intervals for different years.

Answer (score 2):

You want to resample the two dataseries so that they have the same interval and fillna with method 'ffill'

```
df1 = df1.resample('m').fillna(method = 'ffill')
df2 = df2.resample('m').fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering old question hoping to help others.

I had a similar problem but beside the two data frames with the timestamps I had an extra column that defined if the 15~15 min data could match or not within my 1~1min data. It was like a key used on the ON parameter from merge, but as I had those extra data I couldn't use the pd.merge directly.

I found this function that solved directly, including the part of the extra information using the parameter by.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html

The example on the docs is really straightforward.