# merge series/dataframe with different time frequencies in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, merge

i am trying to merge two series, one in hour and another in minute (and keep the index at minute level):

```
Series A:

time
2017-09-01 01:00:00   0.5
2017-09-01 02:00:00   0.4
Freq: H, Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Series B in minute:

```
Series B

time
2017-09-01 00:00:00         NaN
2017-09-01 00:03:00   -0.000350
2017-09-01 00:06:00    0.000401
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

I want to merge the two series by hour. And the desired merged dataframe would be:

```
time
2017-09-01 00:00:00         NaN       0.5
2017-09-01 00:03:00   -0.000350       0.5
2017-09-01 00:06:00    0.000401       0.5
2017-09-01 01:00:00    0.002301       0.4
2017-09-01 01:03:00    0.005601       0.4
```

After searching on SO, one way I found is to create an 'hour' column in series B and then join A to B using the index of A and the 'hour' column of B: (reference: [Merging/combining two dataframes with different frequency time series indexes in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080542/merging-combining-two-dataframes-with-different-frequency-time-series-indexes-in))

```
B = B.to_frame()
B['hour'] = B.index.to_period('H')
merged = B.join(A, on = 'hour', how = 'left')
```

But I got error message:

```
TypeError: Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Index)
```

Does anyone know how to solve the issue? Or maybe there is a better way of joining the two series? Thanks a lot!

Comment: why are you matching hour `01` from series `A`  with hour `00` from series `B`?

Comment: because these are the "returns since the previous row". i.e. 0.5 is the return between 00:00 hour and 01:00 hour. this can be adjusted using shift command, so my main issue is still the difference in frequencies. :(

Comment: i've updated my answer - please check

Comment: thanks! so the trick is resample and ffill!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [280]: A
Out[280]:
time
2017-09-01 01:00:00    0.5
2017-09-01 02:00:00    0.4
Name: val, dtype: float64

In [281]: B
Out[281]:
time
2017-09-01 00:00:00         NaN
2017-09-01 00:03:00   -0.000350
2017-09-01 00:06:00    0.000401
Name: val, dtype: float64

In [282]: B.to_frame('B').join(A.to_frame('A').set_index(A.index.shift(-1, freq='H')).resample('3T').ffill())
Out[282]:
                            B    A
time
2017-09-01 00:00:00       NaN  0.5
2017-09-01 00:03:00 -0.000350  0.5
2017-09-01 00:06:00  0.000401  0.5
```

Comment: sorry i should have been clearer, but I want to keep the merged dataframe at minute level, i.e. index of B. That's why i used (how = 'left'). i have edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: @ian_chan, can you post your desired (output) data set in your question?

Comment: sure thing. just made the changes. sorry for the inconvenience