# Merge dataframes with different datetime frequencies without NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two dataframes with different datetime frequencies and also filling up missing values with duplicates.

Dataframe df1 with minute frequency:

```
    time
0   2017-06-01 00:00:00
1   2017-06-01 00:01:00
2   2017-06-01 00:02:00
3   2017-06-01 00:03:00
4   2017-06-01 00:04:00
```

Dataframe df2 with hourly frequency:

```
    time2               temp    hum
1   2017-06-01 00:00:00 13.5    90.0
2   2017-06-01 01:00:00 12.2    95.0
3   2017-06-01 02:00:00 11.7    96.0
4   2017-06-01 03:00:00 11.5    96.0
5   2017-06-01 04:00:00 11.1    97.0
```

So far i merged these dataframe but get NaNs:

```
m2o_merge = df1.merge(df2, left_on= 'time', right_on= 'time2', how='outer')
m2o_merge.head()

    time       time2                temp    hum
0   2017-06-01 00:00:00 2017-06-01  13.5    90.0
1   2017-06-01 00:01:00 NaT         NaN     NaN
2   2017-06-01 00:02:00 NaT         NaN     NaN
3   2017-06-01 00:03:00 NaT         NaN     NaN
4   2017-06-01 00:04:00 NaT         NaN     NaN
```

My desired dataframe should look like this (NaN filled up with hourly value df2):

```
    time                temp    hum
0   2017-06-01 00:00:00 13.5    90.0
1   2017-06-01 00:01:00 13.5    90.0
2   2017-06-01 00:02:00 13.5    90.0
3   2017-06-01 00:03:00 13.5    90.0
4   2017-06-01 00:04:00 13.5    90.0
...
```

So far i found this solution: [merge series/dataframe with different time frequencies in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253360/merge-series-dataframe-with-different-time-frequencies-in-python), but the Datetime column is not my index. Does anyone know how to get there ?

Comment: In your case you should be able to use ```fillna()``` with the ffill method to get your results. Then drop the time2 column. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna

Comment: Use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Ben Pap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10286422/ben-pap) i did the following two Steps as a solution:

```
import pandas as pd 
data1 = {'time':pd.date_range('2017-06-01 00:00:00','2017-06-01 00:09:00', freq='T')} 
data2 = {'time2':pd.date_range('2017-06-01 00:00:00','2017-06-01 04:00:00', freq='H'), 'temp':[13.5,12.2,11.7,11.5,11.1], 'hum':[90.0,95.0,96.0,96.0,97.0]}

# Create DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2) 

m2o_merge = df1.merge(df2, left_on= 'time', right_on= 'time2', how='outer')
m2o_merge.head()

m2o_merge.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
filled_df = m2o_merge.drop(['time2'], axis=1)
filled_df.head()
```